# How to display a date as ISO8601 with JSTL?

Tags: java, jstl, date-format

Something like?

```jsp
<fmt:formatDate value="${event.starttime}" type="both"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible AFAIK.  You can use the `pattern` attribute:

```
<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz" value="${event.starttime}" />
```

But there is not a pattern to generate ISO8601 without post-processing.  You have to cook your date in the server side and show it in your view.

You might find [Joda-Time library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_iso.html) useful, as well as some blog posts like:

- http://www.coderanch.com/t/376612/Java-General/java/SimpleDateFormat-ISO
- http://www.dynamicobjects.com/d2r/archives/003057.html
- http://developer.marklogic.com/howto/tutorials/2004-09-dates.xqy

Comment: This is unfortunately wrong, ISO 8601 doesn't have the concept of timezones, just an offset of UTC or 'Z' to indicate UTC, I would go for the advise of using Joda-Time, they even have a tagslib

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind that all your dates will be in UTC (or other hardcoded timezone after modification) you can use:

```jsp
<fmt:formatDate value="${event.starttime}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" timeZone="UTC"/>
```